# Ruby - putting array elements into another array in order

Tags: ruby, arrays

`array1 = [ [a], [b], [c], [d], [e] ]`

`array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`

How can I put each of the elements of array2 into each the elements of array1 to get something like:

`array3 = [ [a, 1], [b, 2], [c, 3], [d, 4], ... ]`

I'm trying something like `array1.map { |a| [a, array2.each { |b| b}] }`, but not really sure how to get it yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the value in array2 an index into array1, or do you want to combine the arrays according to their position in each array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just try this using [`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) and [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip)

```
array1 = [ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'] ]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array1.flatten.zip(array2) 
# [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["d", 4], ["e", 5]]
```

More information about `Array#zip` can be found [here](http://dfriedm.github.io/blog/2013/10/12/ruby-zip-method/).

Comment: @QPaysTaxes [This blog post](http://dfriedm.github.io/blog/2013/10/12/ruby-zip-method/) (not mine) has a great explanation of ruby `zip` method.

Comment: @Sid So put it in your answer so that people (like me *cough*) who aren't familiar with .zip can see it right in the an-- oh, you already did. Uh. Good! Good on you. I'm gonna, uh... Be over here.

Answer (score 2):

```
array1 = [ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d','e'] ]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you do not wish to alter `array1` or `array2`:

```
array1.zip(array2).map { |a1,e2| a1 + [e2] }
  #=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["d", "e", 4]]
array1
  #=> [ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d','e'] ]
```

If you do wish to alter `array1` but not `array2`:

```
array1.zip(array2).map { |a1,e2| a1 << e2 }
  #=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["d", "e", 4]]
array1
  #=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["d", "e", 4]]
```

If you do wish to alter `array1` and can also alter `array2`:

```
array1.map { |a| a << array2.shift }
  #=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["d", "e", 4]] 
array1
  #=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["d", "e", 4]] 
array2
  #=> []
```

In the first two cases you could use [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) instead of [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) by replacing `array1.zip(array2)` with `[array1, array2].transpose`.